# Add MouseListener to a JSplitPane Component that is inside the JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jsplitpane

I am in a problem that i do have a JTable and a Column containing the JSplitPane. Now i want to apply MouseClickListener on to the parent and bottom components inside the JSPlitPane.

if i am adding the mouseListener on my jTable, it returns me with complete row. what i am doing is:

**Appplying the Split Pane by using the Cell renderer:**

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new SplitPaneRenderer());
```

**Setting the MouseListener:**

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                    JTable target=(JTable)e.getSource();

                    int row=target.getSelectedRow();
                    int column=target.getSelectedColumn();

                    if(column==3){
                        if(row==0){
                            System.out.println("First row is clicked");
                        }
                    }

                }
    });
```

Please help how can i set the mouselistener to specific component of JSplitPane.

Comment: This isn't really how cell renderers/editors work and I'm kind of scared that you've done this.  Take a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for more details. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: If a cell has _so_ much content that it needs a split pane, consider displaying that content in an adjacent pane or popup dialog.